# Unity3d 2020.3.10f1 and Android 10 - Want to access my GPX Files by reading them from the downloads folder

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Please give advice, since it worked with Android 8. Running it on Android 10 device
results in "Access denied" as exception. Which permissions are needed to be requested, just to read the downloads folder and further read GPX, while it is not a native MIME Type.

Could you please send a short sample, how to set the proper Permission within Unity C# Script?

Thanks in advance,
Oliver

```
     try
    {
        foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("/storage/emulated/0/download"))
        {
            if (file.Substring(file.Length - 4).ToUpper() == ".GPX")
            {
                
                text.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text += file + "\r\n";

            }

        }

        text.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = "Place your GPX Files in here: \r\n" + "/storage/emulated/0/download";

    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        text.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = "Cannot access: " + e.Message.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: The is not a c# issue.  Android 10 is failing to boot properly.  You should connect to android on serial monitor port and check for errors on boot or check the boot log files to see if there are failures.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, well I output the Exception directly to the screen (while developing) 

It says: "ACCESS TO THE PATH /storage/emulated/0/download IS DENIED'.

I am outside of -> Application.persistentDataPath

Comment: @jdweng https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjyYCUW-9tY 
Seams to explain why ... Scoped Storage

Comment: Request legacy external storage in manifest.

Comment: You are using a relative path with respect to folder where c# application is running : /storage/emulated/0/download

Comment: @jdweng see Answer. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thanks @blackapps. Thanks, Rene - https://www.udemy.com/user/rene-buhling/

Worked like a charm ... for Android 10 now ;)

1. I enabled a CUSTOM MAIN MANIFEST in the player settings
   which results in activating Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml
2. In there add the requestLegacyExternalStorage

   ```
    <manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
   ```

Great day ... Thanks

Comment: requestLegacyExternalStorage has no effect on Android 11. Without the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, it is impossible to access most sections of the filesystem using File API (so, this solution won't work on Android 11+). MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission isn't allowed by Google Play unless developer can justify its usage.

Comment: @yasirkula Thanks for contribution. Well, if you want to open any file from the downloads folder ... how is that to be done within 11? 

How is the procedure in the end? Do you have some code samples ...?

Comment: The closest thing I have is [NativeFilePicker](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeFilePicker) which lets you pick a file of specified mime type from anywhere including Downloads. It automatically copies the file to temporaryCachePath because you can't access the original file with File API. The downsides are: user isn't restricted to Downloads folder, he can pick the file from anywhere he wants and only a single mime type is allowed so user can't browse all file types at once.

Comment: [As stated here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#document-tree-access-restrictions), Downloads is a special folder. Otherwise, I'd recommend you [SimpleFileBrowser](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnitySimpleFileBrowser).

Comment: @yasirkula, well Thanks, NativeFilePicker brought me here, because I did not manage GPX, since it is not Native MIME type... Well my solution is listed up  and works great... for And. 10

Comment: Might work to read content with XDocument , since GPX is like XML...